# Angular Directive - require ngModel AND form^

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In an angular directive can you require form^ AND ngModel? Is it possible to access the form and controller within the linking function?

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('passwordValidation', passwordValidation)
function passwordValidation(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel', // also 'form^' ?
    scope: {
      userName: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl, form) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible by providing an array in require property. Using this, you will be provided with array of controllers as 4th argument in link function.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('passwordValidation', passwordValidation)
function passwordValidation(){
  return {
    replace: true,
    require: ['ngModel','^form'], // also 'form^' ?
    scope: {
      userName: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, controllers) {
      var ngModelCtrl = controllers[0],formCtrl = controllers[1]; 
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Haha, I actually tried that but incorrectly had 'form^' . Thanks!